# Add and Remove Class of Tab Onscroll (If else Tab JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, tabs

I want to use `scroll` to add and remove a `class` of Tabs

When I scroll down the page, then all tab switch to active. Then, when I scroll up the page, the all tab switched to inactive.

In the current condition, when I scroll down the page, it removes the current tab `class`, and when I scroll up the page, it adds the active `class` to the first tab. But, it's not what I want. I want it when I scroll down it moves to the next tab, when I scroll up it moves to the previous tab. I think I should use the if else tab.

```js
//Add & remove class tab, contents, & menu on click
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
    let content = document.querySelectorAll('.content-item');
    let firstTab = function(tabs) {tabs.classList.add('tab-active')};
    let firstContent = function(content) {content.classList.add('content-active')};
  
    firstTab(tabs[0]); //Already remove the ready and callback
    firstContent(content[0]);
  
        for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {            
            tabs[i].addEventListener('click', () => tabClick(i));
        }
  
        for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {            
            window.addEventListener('scroll', () => tabScroll(i)); //Already remove the multiple scroll listeners in a loop. But, idk whether it's right or not
        }
  
  
        function tabClick(currentTab) {
          
            //Remove Active Class
            let prevt = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-active')[0];
            let prevc = document.querySelectorAll('.content-active')[0];
            prevc.classList.remove('content-active');
            prevc.classList.add('content-show');
            prevc.querySelector('iframe').removeAttribute('src');
            setTimeout(function() {
              prevc.classList.remove('content-show');
            },1500);
            prevt.classList.remove('tab-active');
            
            //Add Active Class
            const iframe = content[currentTab].querySelector('iframe');
            tabs[currentTab].classList.add('tab-active');
            content[currentTab].classList.add('content-active');
            iframe.setAttribute('src', iframe.getAttribute('data-src'));  
        }
  
  
        function tabScroll(currentTab) {
          if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
            let prevt = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-active')[0];
            let prevc = document.querySelectorAll('.content-active')[0];
            prevc.classList.remove('content-active');
            prevc.classList.add('content-show');
            prevc.querySelector('iframe').removeAttribute('src');
            setTimeout(function() {
              prevc.classList.remove('content-show');
            },1500);
            prevt.classList.remove('tab-active');
            
            //Add Active Class
            const iframe = content[currentTab].querySelector('iframe');
            tabs[currentTab].classList.add('tab-active');
            content[currentTab].classList.add('content-active');
            iframe.setAttribute('src', iframe.getAttribute('data-src'));
          }
        }
     })
```

```css
        .container {
          width: 100vw;
          height: 400px;
        }
        .tabs {
            display: flex;
            height: 65px;
            overflow: hidden;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .tab {
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .tab-active {
            background-color: rgb(250, 97, 9);
        }

        .content {
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 5px;
            height: calc(100% - 65px);
        }

        .content-item {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: none;
            padding: 0px;
            border: none;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .content-wrapper1 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .content-wrapper2 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .content-wrapper3 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        .content-iframe {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .content-show {
            display: flex;
            animation-name: fade-out;
            animation-duration: 2.5s;
        }
        
        @keyframes fade-out {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
                display: flex;
            }
            99% {
                opacity: 0;
                display: flex;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0;
                display: none;
            }
        }

        .content-active {
            display: flex;
            border: none;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
            animation-name: fade-in;
            animation-duration: 2.5s;
        }

        @keyframes fade-in {
            0% {
                display: none;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            1% {
                display: block;
                opacity: 0.01;
            }
            100%{
                display: block;
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        .content-iframe {
            border: none;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 50vh;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="tab">Tokyo</div>
            <div class="tab">Paris</div>
            <div class="tab">Washington</div>
            <div class="tab">Jakarta</div>
            <div class="tab">London</div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me to solve this guys. Thank you so much..

Comment: 1. Remove the weirdness with ready and callback and move the queryselectorAll code insdie DOMContentLoaded handler. 2. Do NOT add multiple scroll listeners in a loop. Only ONE is needed.

Comment: @mplungjan Okay I'm gonna try it, but it might takes time because I don't have a code basic

Comment: @mplungjan is this what you mean about what you commented above, sir?

Comment: @mplungjan I already revised the code in this question, sir. I decided to delete the duplicate question, just not to be confused..